# in Excel , in my pivot tables when i drop down the row fields, value filter option is disabled

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

in Excel , in my pivot tables when i drop down the row fields, value filter option is disabled any idea why ?

Comment: Where is the data source of the pivot table held? Is it visible on another worksheet? Are there any protections on the workbook or worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was opening xls doc in excel 2007 . when i saved it as .xlsx it started working